# Need to disable the enter key on a textedit box or at the form level

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, textbox, enter

Can you show the coding needed to disable the enter key on a textedit box or at the form level?

This form is using multi-line textedit boxes and I would like to prevent the user from pressing the enter key from jumping to the next line in the textedit boxes.

Comment: Ignoring key presses can make for a frustrating user experience, consider notifying the user in some way of why the key was ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would add a handler to the text box's "KeyDown" event and use `KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress`  -- see :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.suppresskeypress.aspx#Y0

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) _
        Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Text boxes also have a `.ReadOnly` property which can be set programatically if you need to temporarily (or permanently) prevent the user from changing the content of the box (ie: for display only).

Comment: @AdamS - I agree, but I feel this depends a lot on the context of the application and the textbox.  Without a better idea of the big picture it's difficult to suggest a better alternative.  Maybe the text box in this case is not the best tool for the job, even.

Comment: Completely agree, +1 to your answer, meant to comment on the OP.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried the code but the enter key was not trapped. I placed a msgbox just to see if it was being trapped. Later I will try a textedit box without multi-line support and see if it will work.

Comment: Perhaps post your code then, because when I try this it works.

Comment: Also, if you're testing this by showing a MsgBox and then dismissing it with the "Enter" key then it won't work - this will only trap key presses directed at the TextBox.  The enter key will still be received by all other objects.

Comment: I discovered that by using the textbox that comes with Visual Studio works with trapping the enter key using your code and the one I used does not. The one I was using is from PureComponents and it seems to be a bit buggy so I will need to use the stock one instead.